Export custom attribute form to PDF
I created a custom form with qt Designer for my tree layer. It looks like this:

Now, I would like to print these forms as PDF. Ideally, I want to select relevant tree objects by expression and then print their attribute forms as PDF. Is that somehow possible?
My first idea was to work with reports. However, I was only able to display the attribute table and not the custom form.

Perhabs there is a way to display my custom form on the report window?
